# could not decode nested json api php

Tags: php, json, api, nested

I am using these code to fetch koinex api data. From this API URL - 
https://koinex.in/api/ticker

```
<?php

$getCurrency = "inr";
$displayArrayOutput = true;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://koinex.in/api/ticker",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    if($displayArrayOutput){
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        print_r($response);

    }
    else{
        header("Content-type:application/json");
    }
}


?>
```

I have also try file_get_contents but same problem. I have face this issue in 2 more api's. Note: Once i get the data and use it correctly but today this is not working again.

Comment: Doesn't `curl_close` free all the resources? So wouldn't `$response` be empty?

Comment: No @Tony. $response was assigned, it is not a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, and apparently the website you are trying to reach with CURL uses a security:

> **Why have I been blocked?**
>
> *This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.*
>
> **What can I do to resolve this?**
>
> *You can email the site owner to let them know you were blocked. Please include what you were doing when this page came up and the Cloudflare Ray ID found at the bottom of this page.*

It seems that the website you are trying to reach asks for a user agent. This code works for me:

```
<?php

$getCurrency = "inr";
$displayArrayOutput = true;

// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://koinex.in/api/ticker',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Something here'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$response = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
} else {
    if($displayArrayOutput){
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        print_r($response);

    }
    else{
        header("Content-type:application/json");
        echo 'touine';
    }
}


?>
```

Good luck

Comment: Good catch. When I tested it, it all just worked fine and I was about to toss "cannot reproduce" :)